# "Hello Word" (html) website in a dedicated server?

Tags: html, dedicated-server

Does anyone know how to launch a simple "Hello Word" (HTML)  website in a dedicated server using a simple HTML file? How to connect the domain name and host to my HTML file located in a dedicated server C:\firstweb\HellowWord.html?

Answer (score 0):

There are many things to consider if you are running something off a server like the web framework that you will be using and the kind of of web server you gonna run your site.  Be a little bit more specific.

Comment: Thanks.  Consider that I have a simple HTML file as follows in my c drive in a dedicated server. How can I assign it to my domain which has been already set to DNS of my host?  like :<head>
<!-- metadata goes in head -->
 <title>My First page</title>
<head>

<body>
<!-- content goes in body -->
 <h1> HelloWorld!!</h1> </body>
</html>

Comment: can i ask what kind of domain/service you get?

Comment: I bought a domain from GoDaddy for one year